# Slice nested list at variable depth

Tags: python

How can I implement the following for arbitrary values of variable 'depth'?

```
if depth == 1:
    txt[0] = txt[0][s:]
if depth == 2:
    txt[0][0] = txt[0][0][s:]
if depth == 3:
    txt[0][0][0] = txt[0][0][0][s:]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop:

```
target = txt
for _ in range(depth - 1):
    target = target[0]
target[0] = target[0][s:]
```

This repeatedly traverses to the next first element; the last level is then replaced by the slice.

Comment: Well done!  I had tried this with range(depth) and had fallen afoul of assigning-by-value.  This did this trick.